# Validate Datatype of Json Nodes (Jackson)

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I am using Jackson parsing to parse a **Json** and saving it to **Hbase**. Prior to save I have to validate the datatype of nodes against a list of datatypes from MySQL. Currently I am following this approach:

```
 def validateNode(node:JsonNode, DataType : String) :Any  = 
 {
      val nodeValue = node.toString()
      DataType.toLowerCase() match {
        case "double" ⇒ {
          try{
          d.toDouble
         }
     catch{
          }

        }
        case "int"    ⇒try { node.getValueAsInt } catch{}
        case "string" ⇒ try{ node.getTextValue }catch{}

      }

    }
```

which looks ugly to me.

a) I am catching the exceptions in every case block to see whether the datatype is correct.

Can somebody suggests me some elegant code for this?

Further, I have to handle some datatypes like `Array` and `Vector` too.
 eg : `JsonNode` would be something like

```
 {"A":[[1,2],[2,4],[4,5]]} (==>Vector of Integer) .
```

Comment: You can simplify your code by using `JsonNode.getNodeType()`, which returns enum `JsonNodeType`. Jackson only constructs valid nodes, meaning that a `JsonNodeType.BOOLEAN` must have come from JSON value `true` or `false`. Another alternative is to use various `isXxx()` methods, like `node.isFloatingPointNumber()`. These are much more efficient than serializing value as a String, then trying to re-parse as number.

Comment: Thanks StaxMan for the suggestion. I can very well use isXxx() methods, but these would be good for String, Double, Float, Int. But I am not able to cater to Vector. Because Vector of Integers in JSON in represented as [[1,2],[2,4],[3,4]] which is an ARRAY if I use JsonNodeType. Further, I need the demarcation like Vector of Double, Vector of String, Vector of Int, etc. Please suggest.

Comment: JSON does not have types, it only has arrays, objects and so on. This is what `JsonNode` can show, as it does not have any information about Java types you want to use. Note also that JSON Arrays are not typed: they may contain values of any JSON types. Typing in your case comes from Java side (Hibernate), and you need to verify it recursively. You can traverse `JsonNode` hierarchy, match `DataType` you have.